# Ambiguousc call of generic method if there is non generic with same name

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have two methods in Factories class:

```
public static List<String> list(final String... elements)
public static <T> List<T> list(final T... elements)
```

Now when I try to make parameterless calls:

```
Factories.list();
Factories.<String>list();
Factories.<Integer>list();
```

I get following error:

the method list(String[]) is ambiguous for the type Factories.

Is there a way in java to pick which version of method I want to call (generic or for strings).

Comment: No. The very fact that you have a generic version *should* mean that you don't need an explicit String version. If there are legitimate differences between how it works for Strings and how it works for other types, the functions shouldn't have the same name.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. On which line does it occur?

Comment: @MCEmperor [Me neither](https://ideone.com/kS3ZIS), actually.

Comment: @Michael Still Java allows to define explicit version so it should provide mechanism to disambiguate invocation.